# Obter INT como INT e não como string - Codeigniter - Ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

Tenho a seguinte `tabela`, `controller` e `model`, quero obter o que é `int` como `int`, e não `string`.

Veja que, quando o item é recuperado, o campo `int` está entre aspas. Como faço para recuperar os dados de forma correta ?

***Tabela***

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_banco`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_banco` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `codigo` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  `nome` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `assessoria_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `dt_cadastro` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `dt_atualizacao` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `situacao` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

***Controller***

```
//Função Obter Banco por ID
public function obter($id)
{
    if ($id == 0)
    {
        $id = $id;
        $dados = $this->banco->json_array($id);
        echo json_encode($dados);
    }
    else
    {
        $dados = $this->banco->obter($id);
        echo json_encode($dados);
    }
}
```

***Model***

```
/*** Obter por ID ***/
public function obter($id)
{
    $this->db->from($this->tbl_banco);
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

***Ajax***

```
function obter(id, acao) {
var ret;
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url : "banco/obter/" + id + "/" + acao,
    success: (function (obj) {          
        _obj = JSON.parse(obj);
        _obj_banco = _obj;
        objeto_form();
        ret = true;
    }),
    error: (function (erro) {
        trata_erro_ajax(erro);
        ret = false;
    })
});
return ret;
}
```

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da pra resolver com `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`, uma opcao do `json_encode` que foi adicionada no PHP 5.3.3

Problema e que isso vai transformar em int todos os numeros que ele conseguir, por exemplo o seu `codigo` vai retornar como `1` ao inves de `001`

É so adicionar a opcao na hora do encode `echo json_encode($dados, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);`

Mais infos voce encontra nos [docs do json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: Mas aí, como voce disse, esta constante `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`, vai forçar o retorno de tudo que é numero, até mesmo se o tipo de campo for `varchar` ou `char`.

Se for para recuperar um `CPF`, cujo primeiro número seja `0`, ele vai desconsiderar este `0`.

Tem alguma outra forma ?

Comment: É aí que encontra a função do controller, tratar os valores e enviar o resultado para o usuário.  Então, o ideal é percorrer o array e tratar os valores.

Comment: É sim, o banco é mysql